# compute the infinity norm of the difference between the two solutions

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code I have been able to:

1. Implement Gaussian elimination with no pivoting for a general square linear system.
2. I have tested it by solving Ax=b, where A is a random 100x100 matrix and b is a random 100x1 vector.
3. I have compared my solution against the solution obtained using numpy.linalg.solve

However in the final task I need to compute the infinity norm of the difference between the two solutions. I know the infinity norm is the greatest absolute row sum of a matrix. But how can I do this to compute the infinity norm of the difference between the two solutions, my solution and the numpy.linalg.solve. Looking for some help with this!

```
import numpy as np
def GENP(A, b):
    '''
    Gaussian elimination with no pivoting.
    % input: A is an n x n nonsingular matrix
    %        b is an n x 1 vector
    % output: x is the solution of Ax=b.
    % post-condition: A and b have been modified. 
    '''
    n =  len(A)
    if b.size != n:
        raise ValueError("Invalid argument: incompatible sizes between A & b.", b.size, n)
    for pivot_row in range(n-1):
        for row in range(pivot_row+1, n):
            multiplier = A[row][pivot_row]/A[pivot_row][pivot_row]
            #the only one in this column since the rest are zero
            A[row][pivot_row] = multiplier
            for col in range(pivot_row + 1, n):
                A[row][col] = A[row][col] - multiplier*A[pivot_row][col]
            #Equation solution column
            b[row] = b[row] - multiplier*b[pivot_row]
    x = np.zeros(n)
    k = n-1
    x[k] = b[k]/A[k,k]
    while k >= 0:
        x[k] = (b[k] - np.dot(A[k,k+1:],x[k+1:]))/A[k,k]
        k = k-1
    return x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = np.round(np.random.rand(100, 100)*10)
    b =  np.round(np.random.rand(100)*10)
    print (GENP(np.copy(A), np.copy(b)))
```

for example this code gives the following output for task 1 listed above:

```
[-6.61537666  0.95704368  1.30101768 -3.69577873 -2.51427519 -4.56927017
 -1.61201589  2.88242622  1.67836096  2.18145556  2.60831672  0.08055869
 -2.39347903  2.19672137 -0.91609732 -1.17994959 -3.87309152 -2.53330865
  5.97476318  3.74687301  5.38585146 -2.71597978  2.0034079  -0.35045844
  0.43988439 -2.2623829  -1.82137544  3.20545721 -4.98871738 -6.94378666
 -6.5076601   3.28448129  3.42318453 -1.63900434  4.70352047 -4.12289961
 -0.79514656  3.09744616  2.96397264  2.60408589  2.38707091  8.72909353
 -1.33584905  1.30879264 -0.28008339  0.93560728 -1.40591226  1.31004142
 -1.43422946  0.41875924  3.28412668  3.82169545  1.96675247  2.76094378
 -0.90069455  1.3641636  -0.60520103  3.4814196  -1.43076816  5.01222382
  0.19160657  2.23163261  2.42183726 -0.52941262 -7.35597457 -3.41685057
 -0.24359225 -5.33856181 -1.41741354 -0.35654736 -1.71158503 -2.24469314
 -3.26453092  1.0932765   1.58333208  0.15567584  0.02793548  1.59561909
  0.31732915 -1.00695954  3.41663177 -4.06869021  3.74388762 -0.82868155
  1.49789582 -1.63559124  0.2741194  -1.11709237  1.97177449  0.66410154
  0.48397714 -1.96241854  0.34975886  1.3317751   2.25763568 -6.80055066
 -0.65903682 -1.07105965 -0.40211347 -0.30507635]
```

then for task two my code gives the following:

```
my_solution = GENP(np.copy(A), np.copy(b))
numpy_solution = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
print(numpy_solution)
```

resulting in:

```
[-6.61537666  0.95704368  1.30101768 -3.69577873 -2.51427519 -4.56927017
-1.61201589  2.88242622  1.67836096  2.18145556  2.60831672  0.08055869
-2.39347903  2.19672137 -0.91609732 -1.17994959 -3.87309152 -2.53330865
 5.97476318  3.74687301  5.38585146 -2.71597978  2.0034079  -0.35045844
 0.43988439 -2.2623829  -1.82137544  3.20545721 -4.98871738 -6.94378666
-6.5076601   3.28448129  3.42318453 -1.63900434  4.70352047 -4.12289961
-0.79514656  3.09744616  2.96397264  2.60408589  2.38707091  8.72909353
-1.33584905  1.30879264 -0.28008339  0.93560728 -1.40591226  1.31004142
-1.43422946  0.41875924  3.28412668  3.82169545  1.96675247  2.76094378
 -0.90069455  1.3641636  -0.60520103  3.4814196  -1.43076816  5.01222382
 0.19160657  2.23163261  2.42183726 -0.52941262 -7.35597457 -3.41685057
-0.24359225 -5.33856181 -1.41741354 -0.35654736 -1.71158503 -2.24469314
-3.26453092  1.0932765   1.58333208  0.15567584  0.02793548  1.59561909
 0.31732915 -1.00695954  3.41663177 -4.06869021  3.74388762 -0.82868155
 1.49789582 -1.63559124  0.2741194  -1.11709237  1.97177449  0.66410154
 0.48397714 -1.96241854  0.34975886  1.3317751   2.25763568 -6.80055066
-0.65903682 -1.07105965 -0.40211347 -0.30507635]
```

finally for task 3:

```
if np.allclose(my_solution, numpy_solution):
    print("These solutions agree")
else:
   print("These solutions do not agree")
```

resulting in:

```
These solutions agree
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want to compute infinity norm of `my_solution - numpy_solution`?

Comment: yes exactly! would you know how to do this?

Comment: and I believe its absolute values

Comment: Well something like `max(abs(row.sum()) for row in (a - b))` seems like what you want. I'm a bit puzzled, because you posted a lot of code for gaussian elimination which, it seems to me, has nothing to do with what you really wanted, which is just the norm... at least that's how I understand it.

Comment: Or is it because you have 2 _row_ vectors and you need each member of vector as a row by itself? Then just reshape the difference: `.. (a - b).reshape((100, 1))`.

Comment: I just wanted to post it to make sure people could see the progress I have worked through if they had any questions

Comment: could you post an answer then I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is only the infinity norm for matrix,
it generally should look something like this:

```
def inf_norm(matrix):
    return max(abs(row.sum()) for row in matrix)
```

But since your `my_solution` and `numpy_solution` are just 1-D vectors, you
may either to reshape them (I assume 100x1 which is what you have in your
example) for use with above function:

### alternative 1:

```
def inf_norm(matrix):
    return max(abs(row.sum()) for row in matrix)

diff = my_solution - numpy_solution
inf_norm_result = inf_norm(diff.reshape((100, 1))
```

### alternative 2:

Or if you know they will always be 1-D vectors, you can omit the sum
(because the rows will all have length 1) and compute it directly:

```
abs(my_solution - numpy_solution).max()
```

### alternative 3:

or as it is written in `numpy.linalg.norm` (see below) documentation:

```
max(sum(abs(my_solution - numpy_solution), axis=1))
```

### alternative 4:

or use the `numpy.linalg.norm()` (see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
np.linalg.norm(my_solution - numpy_solution, np.inf)
```

Comment: okay so by using abs(my_solution-numpy_solution).max() this will calculate the infinity norm difference between the two matrices?

Comment: so because both answers are 100x1 what you have done is taken the max row of each and subtracted thenm?

Comment: No, because you don't have matrices. You have 2 vectors, therefore the difference is only a vector. The "simple" solution works only in the case of vectors. If you want matrices, you need the `inf_norm` function. Or you can use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html with `ord=np.inf` if you just want to compute it and it's not an assignment to actually implement the inf.norm.

Comment: No. I subtracted the vectors first. That's why I separated it into two lines - first compute the difference, then the norm of the difference. You need to understand that norm applies to a vector or matrix, not 2 vectors or two matrices - then it would be a distance not a norm.

Comment: sorry I am getting a little confused, can you just leave the code in your answer that I need to use, just one version of it

Comment: then I can try and understand

Comment: I can see that you're confused, that's ok, we all are sometimes :). So I'll leave them all (I'll add numbers to them) - they all do the same thing, so just select one which seems like most understandable and try it. Then, if you still need help, post comment with the nuber of the variant you're trying and I can expand the answer. But I want to keep all variants there, because this answer is not just for you, but for anyone who'll search stackoverflow with the similar problem.

Comment: haha thanks, if you could just put all the different variants all together and separated it would be great!

Comment: I was just confused which ones to put together

Comment: okay so I am trying 2, I can just plug that in in the bottom of my code and get the solution?

Comment: Well, there is only one way to find out.. :)

Comment: yes I plugged it in, I am getting a very large number tho, I thought it would be smaller

Comment: nvm got a much smaller answer as expected thank you very much for your detailed answer and patience!

Comment: Edit your question and write it there. Because it should be small. Very small. Btw, I'm getting a feeling you're not so much confused but more like you have very little or no experience with programing - if that's the case, it would be better to read some tutorials for numpy/python, try something simpler and try to understand what's it all about.